# How can a custom component handle events of its children?

Tags: delphi, events, custom-controls

I'm designing a panel descendant component that has a button control on it:

```
THidePanel = class(TPanel)
private
  TActivateButton: TButton;
public
  constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent); override;
  procedure WMSize(var Msg: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
  procedure HideComponents;
end;
```

How can this component handle the OnClick event of its TActivateButton control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the button is private to the component you can just attach an eventhandler to it, ie

```
THidePanel = class(TPanel)
  ...
  private
    procedure H_ActivateButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  ...
end;

constructor THidePanel.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
  FActivateButton := TButton.Create(Self);
  FActivateButton.Parent := Self;
  FActivateButton.OnClick:= H_ActivateButtonClick;
end

procedure THidePanel.H_ActivateButtonClick(Sender: TObject)
begin
  // button is clicked!
end
```

If you also need to provide an event to the end user of the compnent then you need to add an `TNotifyEvent` property and call it from your internal handler, ie

```
THidePanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FOnActivateBtnClick: TNotifyEvent;
  ...
  published
    property OnActivateButtonClick: TNotifyEvent read FOnActivateBtnClick write FOnActivateBtnClick;
end;

procedure THidePanel.H_ActivateButtonClick(Sender: TObject)
begin
  // button is clicked!
  ...
  // fire the end user event
  if(Assigned(FOnActivateBtnClick))then FOnActivateBtnClick(Self);
end
```

Comment: Added an example for "end user event" too.

Comment: that makes it a 100% answer.